# Supporting both Multipart and Application Url Encoded parameters in Jersey

Tags: forms, jersey, multipartform-data

I have a rest service in Jersey. I would like to have some post method that accepts parameters both as multipart and as url encoded. I started with :

```
@POST
@Path("/some/resource")
public String addSomeResource(@FormParam("param") String param) {
     repository.add(new SomeResource(param));
}
```

My understanding is that using @Consumes more narrowly defines what's acceptable, and sure enough, this method is called whether someone attaches form data the usual way

```
$.ajax({url:'/some/resource', type:'POST', data:'&param=foo'});
```

or via a multipart form submission (from some Java client wrapping http client).

But when it comes in via multipart - the mapping doesn't happen and `param` is null. I am assuming that that is because it is expecting a `@FormDataParam` and not a `@FormParam` in the method - but I also believe that I can only use `@FormDataParam` when I've more narrowly defined the Consumes as Multipart-only. The documentation for `FormDataParam` (http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html) seems to imply that `FormDataParam` can fall back on `FormData` if no multipart parameter is there.

My current solution to this is to have two methods for each post option:

```
@POST
@Path("/some/resource")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String addSomeResource(@FormParam("param") String param) {
     repository.add(new SomeResource(param));
}
@POST
@Path("/some/resource")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String addSomeResourceMP(@FormDataParam("param") String param) {
     return addSomeResource(param);
}
```

Which seems like it might work, but I wonder if I'm just misunderstanding something more fundamental here, or missing a different fix that is a little better.

Comment: I was looking for a better answer myself, and your unanswered question makes me think there isn't one, which is itself an answer.  Thanks.