# Jersey switch on Content Type dynamically

Tags: java, post, jersey, mailgun

A similar question is here: [Supporting both Multipart and Application Url Encoded parameters in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133681/supporting-both-multipart-and-application-url-encoded-parameters-in-jersey)

I have an API endpoint (in Jersey) that can accepts POST request. The content types are either: form-urlencoded, or multipart. The two types of request arrive at the same path. How do I switch on that?

For the urlencoded request, I want to get argument:

```
@FormParam("recipient") String recipient
```

For multipart request, I want to get:

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Jersey only allows a single method for each unique `@Path` & `@VERB` pair, meaning that you'll either need to have one of those things use a different verb (POST and PUT) or you need two different paths.  Before you just go and make one POST and the other PUT, make sure you understand how to [properly use verbs in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest).